# filling image button inside layout param: android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating a simple toolbar using RelativeLayout

and to a button image i am using following code,

```
ImageButton back = new ImageButton(ctx.getContext());
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams backLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                backLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);


                back.setLayoutParams(backLayoutParams);
                back.setContentDescription("Back Button");
                back.setId(2);
                try {
                    back.setImageBitmap(loadDrawable("icon_left.png"));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                }
                back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                       //
                    }
                });
```

for adding it to the toolbar

```
toolbar.addView(back);
```

for toolbar i am using,

```
RelativeLayout toolbar = new RelativeLayout(ctx.getContext());
toolbar.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,60));
```

Problem is that the button image doesnt FILLS inside layout param.

i tried using setMargin it works, but it doesnot scales with various screen resolutions.

[image]

Need directions on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `ImageButton` has a button background behind its image just like `Button` does behind its text.

Disable the background by calling `setBackgroundDrawable(null)` in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the back image as the background - it should be scaled automatically by the Android Operating System. I advise you turn that image into a .9.png so that it doesnt stretch the text, just the button appearance you have.

BTW, awesome looking button there.

EDIT:
After looking carefully at your code, i think you can simply replace the code

```
back.setImageBitmap(loadDrawable("icon_left.png"));
```

with

```
back.setBackgroundDrawable(loadDrawable("icon_left.png"));
```

Comment: you should use the following xml code: 

    android:background="@drawable/icon_left.png"

Comment: i am looking for a code based solution rather than xml one. thnx for the response though

Comment: mashit, if my solution worked for you, you can unselect the answer that was given and select mine if you like.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't fill the layout because you wrote:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams backLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

What's the result you want?

Comment: i want to show a image button which should auto scale depending on screen size.